# How to add error for MUI TextField that is inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using material-ui TextField component as my text field. I want to generate a red error outline when the required fields are empty after the user clicks on submit, however, in my case below I have an array that I have to loop through, `GET_TEXTFIELD`, so if one of those ids are missing e.g M1 then it will throw an error for all the other TextFields i.e. M2 and M3 which is not expected behavior since the user may have already entered values for those TextFields.

How can I go about doing this? I could do `error={errors.M1?.type === 'required'}` but then it will throw error for field M2 and M3 which is not what I want.

```
const { register, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext();
const GET_TEXTFIELD = { v1: 'M1', v2: 'M2', v3: 'M3' };

<Box display="flex">
        {SOME_ARRAY.map((input) => (
            <TextField
                  {...register(GET_TEXTFIELD[input.fieldId], { required: true })}
                  placeholder="Enter relevant additional information"
                  fullWidth
                  multiline
                  error={// what should my logic be here?}
            />
        )
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a lot of assumptions about your component to create a component that does what you want. You didn't provide enough code to work with. I hope this aligns with your component code or at least you find it useful to implement your own version. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lake-pfp4wk?file=/src/App.js) is a working example.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField, Box, Button } from "@mui/material";

const FormComponent = () => {
  const methods = useForm();
  const GET_TEXTFIELD = { v1: "M1", v2: "M2", v3: "M3" };

  const handleSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    // Your submit logic here
  };

  const SOME_ARRAY = [
    { fieldId: "v1" },
    { fieldId: "v2" },
    { fieldId: "v3" }
    // Add more items as needed
  ];

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(handleSubmit)}>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
          {SOME_ARRAY.map((input) => (
            <TextField
              key={input.fieldId}
              {...methods.register(GET_TEXTFIELD[input.fieldId], {
                required: true
              })}
              label={`Field ${input.fieldId}`}
              placeholder="Enter relevant additional information"
              fullWidth
              multiline
              variant="outlined"
              error={Boolean(
                methods.getValues(GET_TEXTFIELD[input.fieldId]) &&
                  methods.formState.errors[GET_TEXTFIELD[input.fieldId]]
              )}
              helperText={
                methods.formState.errors[GET_TEXTFIELD[input.fieldId]]
                  ? "This field is required"
                  : ""
              }
            />
          ))}
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```